# Vite / SASS - Unknown Word

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vite

I am migrating my Vue 3 project from Webpack to Vite and everything worked fine, except when I wanted to migrate the CSS file. I'm having issues when importing SASS from a package named [bulma-block-list](https://github.com/chrisrhymes/bulma-block-list) - it gives me an "unknown word" error.

You can see the issue reproducing here here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-tuszky?file=src/style.css

I'd like to mention that I added `sass` to package.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your stackblitz:

1. You're importing an `scss` dependency in a `.css` file. Because it's a `.css` file, it won't be parsed by the sass loader.

**Fix**: change `style.css` to `style.scss`

---

2. In [bulma-block-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bulma-block-list)'s description, 2nd item says:

> - *[...] after importing Bulma*.

**Fix**: install and import `bulma-scss` before importing `bulma-block-list`.

---

See it [working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bulma-block-list-vite?file=src%2Fstyle.scss).

Comment: Thank you! For your second point, in my actual project I had bulma imported first but for the stackblitz example I tried having the minimum to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @janos, roger that. Don't take it personally :). I'll leave it in, maybe it will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Not taking it personally, I'm happy that my issue got solved. :) Thanks again.